# How to set value of a model form's readonly (disabled) field to its initialized value when the form is posted?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm creating a form for authors to write articles. The form contains an `author` and a `status` field. I want these two fields, allowed to be changed only if the user is a superuser. If they are not a superuser, it is initialized with their username as `author` and draft, as `status`. I managed to do that but when I submit the form, It is considered to be invalid and returns the form page with errors that say status and author fields are required and they are also not disabled anymore! Does Django ignore the values of read only fields in this case or... ? How can I fix it?

Model form:

```py
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'category', 'description', 'thumbnail', 'status', 'author']
```

view:

```py
def add_update_article(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:home'))
        return render(request, 'registration/add-update-article.html', {
            'form': form
        })
    else:
        if not (request.user.is_author or request.user.is_superuser):
            raise Http404

        form = ArticleForm(initial={'author': request.user, 'status': 'd'})
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            form.fields['author'].disabled = True
            form.fields['status'].disabled = True
        return render(request, 'registration/add-update-article.html', {
            'form': form
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the initial values to the ArticleForm after POST request.
They are not disabled anymore because you are in the other branch of the if statement.

```
def add_update_article(request):
    if not (request.user.is_author or request.user.is_superuser):
      raise Http404

    initial_fields = {'author': request.user, 'status': 'd'}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES, initial=initial_fields)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:home'))
    else:
        form = ArticleForm(initial=initial_fields )

    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        form.fields['author'].disabled = True
        form.fields['status'].disabled = True

    return render(request, 'registration/add-update-article.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```